# Force CSS to apply media query for 1000px when the mobile device is less than 1000px

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, device

I am wondering if it is possible with that following scenario:

I have Media Query css for min-width of 700px and max-width 1000px (normally used for mobile device rendering on browsers)

but, when the older mobile devices with less than 1000px or around 300px, force the site to apply media query for min-width of 700px and max-width of 1000px?

I appreciate response and input.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) , screen and (max-device-width:300px) 
{...}
```

Try max-device-width:300px